# Rails - Nginx not caching images

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I've got a VPS where I'm running my Rails app using Nginx and Unicorn. I was successful to add expires headers to JS and CSS files, however I cannot force Nginx to cache images as well (according to YSlow and Google PageSpeed Insights).

Here's my server block:

```
server {
  listen   80;
  root /home/rails/public;
  server_name _;
  index index.htm index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }

  location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires max;
  }

}
```

The last piece of code is how I have acheived chaching of CSS and JS, but it is not working for images. What am I doing wrong? Should I do some additional changes elsewhere?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two location blocks matching images :

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
    try_files $uri @app;
}
```

And

```
location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires max;
}
```

Nginx will stop at the first matching regex location block so the second location block is **never used** for jpg, jpeg, png, gif and ico files.

**Update** : details for the fallback caching

```
server {
  listen   80;
  root /home/rails/public;
  server_name _;
  index index.htm index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires max;
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    if ($uri ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$) {
        expires max;
    }
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, how do you recommend to accomplish it? Exclude images from both of them and creating a separate one for images that will have both `try_files` and `expires` ?

Comment: I did it by the above described way, fortunatelly it works (big thank you!), but it doesn't work for favicon. Can you suggest how to acheive caching for favicon as well?

Comment: @kellins Is the favicon provided by the fallback location @app?  Do you try to achieve caching only in the case that static files aren't served by the fallback or you want it cached in both cases?

Comment: For uknown reason it wasn't working for favicon and after a while it was :) So thanks a lot for your time. And yes, I would like to be able to cache assets in either case.

Comment: @kellins Ok so it's kinda double caching. You'll have to set the expires directive in the fallback block and filter by extension.

Comment: So you don't recommend that? This is what I've got now `location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
    try_files $uri @app;
    expires max;
  }`

Comment: @kellins Check updated answer.

Comment: thank you, is this with double caching or some kind of recommended? :)